# Write Anchor Text with query value in URL

Tags: javascript

I've searched this forum extensively and was able to come up ( at least I thought) with pieces of codes I need for doing this:

Primary link:
testsite.com/site1/?ADSET=1

I want to take that value for ADSET ( 1 ) and add it to an anchor link like this:

nextsite.com/?tid=1

for accomplish this I got the following pieces of code

First I have this between HEAD

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) {
  url = window.location.href;
}
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

}

THEN THIS in the body ( this is a WP site )

```
var adset = getParameterByName('ADSET');
var link = "http://finalsite.com/click?tid=" + adset;

document.write('<a href="' + link + '"> HYPERLINK TEXT</a>');
```

PROBLEM:

for testing I manually set ADSET=X in the URL just to get the variable ( dont have a way to see if it is actually writting the variable adset)

but the anchor text is empty where it supposed to be.

can't figure out why or how to fix it.

Does anyone has any idea?
If there is a better way to do it ( and not use document.write ) even better.

Answer (score 0):

did not reviewed those regex, but here you have a couple of improvements to start with

```html
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) {
    url = window.location.href;
  }
  //name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) {
    console.log('!results => return null');
    return null;
  }
  if (!results[2]) {
    console.log('!results[2] => return ""');
    return '';
  }
  var r = decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  console.log('returning: "' + r + '"');
  return r;
}
</script>

<p>THEN THIS in the body ( this is a WP site )
<br/>
<a href="#" id="my-anchor">HYPERLINK TEXT</a>

<script>

var adset = getParameterByName('ADSET');
var link = "http://finalsite.com/click?tid=" + adset;

document.getElementById('my-anchor').href = link;

</script>
```

Comment: thanks,
I've applied this but still getting something weird..
http://example.com/article/?ADSET=blue#

where http://example.com/article/ is the article site I am running this on
So basically it is just adding # at the end instead of replacing the link with the new site

Comment: Never mind.. I got it to work.. typo on my side.Thanks!